# Java HttpServletRequest Issue

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I have a web service hosted for sharing transaction details. There are two clients connected with my web service. 
User setup at my end is like below

1. KEJESTORE     ====    201.XXX.XX.XX
2. MARIOBROS     ====    81.XX.XX.XX

I get their Username and ip address of the client server for security reasons using the below method in each time when they call transaction method;

```
MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) msgCtxt.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
String clientIp = req.getRemoteAddr();
String user = wsCtxt.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

But I get results like below some times (This happens very rarely).

1. KEJESTORE   ===    81.XX.XX.XX
2. MARIOBROS   ===    201.XXX.XX.XX

I can not figure out if there is any problem with my above code which i'm using for this purpose.

Please advice.

Edit:

Method

```
public TranResponse sendTransaction(WebServiceContext wsCtxt, Transaction tran){

    MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) msgCtxt.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    String clientIp = req.getRemoteAddr();
    String user = wsCtxt.getUserPrincipal().getName();

// more code

}
```

Comment: This may be due to threading issue. Are you doing it in a thread-safe code?

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. Currently im not using a thread safe code for this. But as i know servlet starts new thread per each request. A'm i correct?

Comment: There are chances that *you have any static method or member which is involved in the servlet*. You could have used an *static utility method* to parse the request. that may be the problem. Just check there if any!

Comment: No Sir. I did not use any static method for this

Comment: Is there any chances the authenticated usernames are working intechangeably? Can you post the method where the above code is?

Comment: Please refer the code under EDIT